# Alias Interface

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface that implements a base interface. A pattern we use for common DB tasks. I then have a Factory class that returns the concrete implementation of the Interface.

Whilst this works fine, I currently have to create a concrete class for each interface, even if the interface currently has no additional methods beyond the first.

```
public static class Factory
{
    public static T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ICustomerRepo))
            return (new CustomerRepo()as T);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ISalesOrderRepo))
            return (new SalesOrderRepo() as T);
        else
            return null;
    }
}

public interface IBaseRepo<C> where C: class, new()
{
    C GetDataById(int Id);
}

public class BaseRepo<C> : IBaseRepo<C>
{
    public C GetDataById(int Id)
    {
        // ... Do Work
        return default(C);
    }
}

public interface ICustomerRepo : IBaseRepo<Customer>
{

}

public class CustomerRepo: BaseRepo<Customer>, ICustomerRepo
{

}

public interface ISalesOrderRepo : IBaseRepo<SalesOrder>
{
    List<SalesOrder> GetAllOrders();
}

public class SalesOrderRepo : BaseRepo<SalesOrder>, ISalesOrderRepo
{

    public List<SalesOrder> GetAllOrders()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Is there a pattern I can use that would allow me to define the `ICustomerRepo` interface, but have the Factory return an instance of BaseRepo, so that I don't need concrete implementations when there are no additional methods?

```
public static class Factory
{
    public static T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ICustomerRepo))
            return (new BaseRepo<Customer>() as T);
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ISalesOrderRepo))
            return (new SalesOrderRepo() as T);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

I'm aware that this is, strictly speaking, not possible, since the Child interface (`ICustomerRepo`) *may* have additional methods that the compiler can't know about.

I could also have the calling code ask for `IBaseRepo<Customer>` rather than `ICustomerRepo`, which would get the same results, but I would prefer to have the calling code continue to reference `ICustomerRepo`.

Is there any pattern that would allow me to create an alias to `IBaseRepo<Customer>` called ICustomerRepo, that would mean that I could later create a concrete implementation without needing to change the calling code?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in simple way - you want to return instance of class that implements ICustomerRepo but BaseRepo does not implement it.

The only solution will be emitting implementation of ICustomerRepo interface dynamically (using Reflection.Emit) but it will require more work that adding CustomerRepo